# How to change the toolbar separator image?

Tags: 11.04, themes, gnome-classic

Is there any way to change the toolbar separator image or make it transparent?

[image]

This affects all applications such as nautilus, gedit...

N.B. my theme isn't the default theme, it's Lion theme from Dolsilwa (deviantart).

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 (GNOME classic).

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the theme's files (such as the gtkrc) to determine how the toolbars will look.